# What is the meaning of | operator?

Tags: definition

For example, 12|0 = 0

Interesting I can't find this on google anywhere.

Which logical connective is this?

as in this article

http://www.mathblog.dk/strong-induction/

Comment: Context? I.e., where do you encounter this? What kind of book/article/...?

Comment: strong induction article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, $\mid$ is a *relation*: $m \mid n$ means that $m$ divides $n$, or equivalently $n$ is a multiple of $m$. This means that there is an integer $\ell$ such that

$$ n = \ell m.$$

If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers with $m \mid n$, then we must have $m \le n$. The symbol "$\mid$" is read *divides* and is produced by `\mid` in $\LaTeX$.

Therefore the proposition in the article, "if $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $12 \mid (n^4 - n^2)$", simply means that $n^4 - n^2$ is divisible by $12$ for each natural number $n$.

However note that the notation in the article is somewhat abusive in that, for instance

> $12 \mid (1^4 - 1^2) = 12 \mid (1- 1) = 0 = 0*12$

should instead be something like

> $12 \mid (1^4 - 1^2) \iff 12 \mid (1- 1) \iff 12 \mid 0$, which is true since $\overbrace{0}^n = \overbrace{0}^\ell \times \overbrace{12}^m$ (or since $0$ is a multiple of $12$).

Comment: _Somewhat_ abusive? Hm.  From the article, it looks like $$12 \mid (1^4 - 1^2) = 12 \mid (1- 1) = 0 = 0*12$$ is a very confusing shorthand for $$12 \mid (1^4 - 1^2) = 12 \mid (1- 1)$$ $\land$ $$(1- 1) = 0 = 0*12$$

Comment: @MarnixKlooster, Yes, I am not so sure about this article. @$ $Alfred, I advise you to stick to the [source (page 160)](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/Induction.pdf), from which this example is "shamelessly stolen". By the way the whole book (Richard Hammack's _Book of Proof_) is available for free [online](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/) if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

In the C programming language, it means the bitwise "or" function.  Write your numbers in base 2, and then "or" each corresponding digit.

E.g. 5|3 = 7, 8|3 = 11.

Comment: @SMS +1. Wow, didn't know you were on this site. I go to Mizzou. Are you teaching PDE in the spring?

Comment: Yes.  I just found out a week ago I am teaching PDE.  I got into this site a weeks ago.  It is very addictive.  It means your homework and tests will take even longer to grade!

Comment: Now you know you can't do [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256816/if-n-the-order-of-a-group-and-gcdk-n-1-then-there-exists-an-element-in) :)